# My action is taking time in executing with Struts2 jQuery Plugin

Tags: struts, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin

I am using Struts2 jQuery Plugin 3.2.1 for ajax and widgets. my actions are taking time in executing when i use sj actions. Without Struts2 jQuery tags , it is  working fine. I searched on net but i am unable to find appropriate answer. Please share your views. Thanks in advance.

- In local server  it is working fine.
- sj actions means , when i click on struts 2 jquery button tag it calls one action.
- Taking time means , target jsp taking time to be loading.

  ```
     <s:url id="increasedaycount" action="AddDayAction"/> <!--when i click on this button one action call but in target result jsp taking time to be appear -->
              <sj:submit
                  href="%{increasedaycount}"
                  button="true"
                  value="Add Day"
                  indicator="indicator"
                  targets="idRightMainDiv"
                  ></sj:submit>
     <img id="indicator" src="images/indicatorS.gif" alt="Loading..." style="display:none"/>
  ```

Comment: sj actions ? Taking time ? Be more explicit to enable others to help...

Comment: @AndreaLigios  i updated my question, please  review it and give suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine in your local server, it's probably some kind of network issue, not a code issue (the code works fine in one machine and doesn't in another...).

Try looking at the network settings from the non-local server to the internet,
and ensure you are not reading jQuery libraries through a CDN (remote hosting of the libraries), you should instead put them physically into your web application...